# Website goes off-screen in height

Tags: html, css, web, scrollbar

I am building this website and created a nice layout for what I need. However on a smaller (laptop) screens the content is higher than the screen, and it does not allow one to scroll up and down. Instead it keeps showing the exact center of my content.

How would I add a scroll-bar to the entire page, so people are not fixed to the center of the page only ?

My current css:

```
<style>
      .centered {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }

      #maincanvas{
        position:fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width:700px;
        height:800px;
        /* background: background="static/bg02.png";*/
        /*border: 15px solid #cc0000;*/
        padding: 25px;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
      #logobox{
        position:absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 50px;
        width:600px;
        height:50px;
        /*border: 10px solid #cc0000;*/
        padding: 25px;
      }

      #contentbox{
        position:absolute;
        top: 200px;
        left: 50px;
        width:600px;
        height:400px;
        background: #f5f5dc;
        border: 10px solid #cc0000;
        padding: 25px;
      }

      #footerbox{
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        left: 50px;
        width:600px;
        height:30px;
        background: #f5f5dc;
        border: 10px solid #cc0000;
        padding: 25px;
      }
      #footerlogo{
        overflow:hidden;
        position:fixed;
        bottom: 30px;
        right: 5px;
        background: #f5f5dc;
        border: 10px solid #cc0000;
        overflow: hide;
        width:250px;
        height:30px;
        padding: 25px;
      }
      /*input[type=text] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 3px solid #ccc;
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
        transition: 0.5s;
        outline: none;
      }*/

input[type=text]:focus {
    border: 3px solid #555;
}

      .widthSet {
        max-width: 150px;
        position:fixed;
        bottom: 35px;
      }
      .alignleft {
        float: left;
      }
      .alignright {
        float: right;
      }
</style>
```

The site content:

```
  <body background="static/bg.png">
    <div id="maincanvas">
      <div id="logobox">
      </div>
      <div id="contentbox">
        $:content
      </div>
      <div id="footerbox">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I have tried playing with different overflow settings, however so far, didn't manage the result I am after. With overflow I can only scroll the content of the boxes, however what I need is to scroll the site (canvas?)

Hoping this is not a duplicate, as I did search, but maybe lack the exact keyword to search for.

Comment: Are you using HTML5? So why: `background="static/bg.png">`, that is the first thing that is not going to work.

Comment: The issue is you're using `position: fixed`. If you were using `position: absolute;` then you'd be able to add `body { overflow-y: scroll; }` to fix your problem. Fixed is fixed. Please [read the following first two sentences of `fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values). Perhaps a little context as to the layout your attempting to achieve would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're running into is the use of `position: fixed;`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values) regaurding *fixed positioning*.

> **Fixed Positioning:** Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled.

So adding scroll to an overflow property won't do anything. The element with *fixed positioning* isn't taking up any space and will always be positioned relative to the viewport in some way.

What you want is `position: absolute;` and a modification to your `top` attribute for smaller screens.

---

```css
#maincanvas {
  /* Note: we could use margin: 0 auto; to center but on larger screens we need left and top set to center inside viewport */
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 700px;
  height: 800px;
  padding: 25px;
  transform: translateX(-50% );
}
#logobox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 10px solid #cc0000;
  padding: 25px;
}
#contentbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #f5f5dc;
  border: 10px solid #cc0000;
  padding: 25px;
}
#footerbox {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f5f5dc;
  border: 10px solid #cc0000;
  padding: 25px;
}
#footerlogo {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 5px;
  background: #f5f5dc;
  border: 10px solid #cc0000;
  overflow: hide;
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 25px;
}
/* When viewport is large enough to start centering #main */

@media (min-height: 800px) {
    #maincanvas {
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="maincanvas">
  <div id="logobox">
  </div>
  <div id="contentbox">
    $:content
  </div>
  <div id="footerbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

For what it's worth, there's a lot to be desired in your markup. You don't need all the absolute positioning you're using. Try and re-use styles if you can. Here is one way you could simplify things.

**Note:** I replicated your margins on the DIVs inside `#main` which will create a horizontal scrollbar on narrower viewports. Not sure what is intended here. Perhaps some styling on `#main` that was not provided in post?

```css
#main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 700px;
  height: 800px;
  padding: 25px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#main > div {
  margin: 0 50px 50px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #f5f5dc;
  border: 10px solid #C00;
}
#main > div:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#logo {
  height: 50px;
}
#content {
  height: 400px;
}
#footer {
  height: 30px;
}
/* When you know the viewport is large enought to try and center ALL of #main */

@media (min-height: 800px) {
  #main {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>
      Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content.
      Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content. Content.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: A very complete answer, thank you for your efforts. You have to understand this was my first attempt at writing a css based website, and i will spend the rest of the night taking apart your examples :) 

The solution was right on the money and the fact that the object was not taking up any space was exactly why I was experiencing the behaviour that I was seeing.

Comment: I figured you my be new to the game. That's why I offered a second, streamlined solution. Which, ultimately, could be refined more. Cheers! (There's even a way to use `position: fixed;` with a tad bit of JS but didn't want to go too overboard!)

Comment: Avoiding JS is a good thing, gotta stay as pure as possible to using 1 solution/language where necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you want to have in your css. Try this and it will look a lot better. You can move the div's itself with the margin-top.

```
  #maincanvas{
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    width:700px;
    height:800px;
    padding: 25px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

Try it!